# How can I add Element objects into other Element Object using dom4j

Tags: xml, dom4j

I'm using dom4j to create a XML. I would like to add sub tags into another tag, as following.

Before:

```
<section>  
    <title>Nice</title>
</section>
```

After

```
<section>
   <title>Nice<title>
   <entry>Hi</entry>
   <entry>wow</entry>
</section>
```

the tag "entry" are other Element Object coming from some api, and I try to such as

```
Element section = component.addElement("section");
section.add(entry);
or
section.addElement(entry);
```

but just get errors.
How can I add Element objects into other Element Object?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();

    Document doc = reader.read("xxx.xml");

    Element root = doc.getRootElement();

    Element entry = DocumentHelper.createElement("entry");
    entry.setText("Hi");

    root.element("section").add(entry);

    OutputFormat format = OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint();
    format.setEncoding("utf-8");
    XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(new FileOutputStream("xxx.xml"),format);
    writer.write(doc);
    writer.close();
```